# Cannot get all memory stats for libvirt domain

Tags: linux, qemu, libvirt, virsh

I'm experiencing some problems with virtual machine (guest windows 7, x86_64), running under qemu-kvm and managed by libvirt (created and ran mostly from virt-manager). The problem is that I cannot get full memory statistics either from running

```
virsh -c qemu:///system dommemstat win7
```

or by calling the

```
virDomainMemoryStats(...)
```

from c++ code (which is, as far as I understood, more or less same things). I also tested libvirt 35th example from [libvirt aplication dev guide](http://libvirt.org/docs/libvirt-appdev-guide-python/en-US/html/libvirt_application_development_guide_using_python-Guest_Domains-Monitoring-Memory.html). This really concerns me, because right now I am working under project, aimed to auto-set the optimal size of memory for vm and hence I need them in my code.

The only output I get from the virsh is

```
actual 4194304
last_update 1500404513
rss 4161676
```

After searching the web I found out that these are the stats, which libvirt can obtain without applying to ballooning driver. However I already installed VirtIO ballooning driver in windows and the system claims that it is running. I don't really know, how to find out whether the qemu is aware of it or not (opened for your ideas).

Also I found that I need to set statistics period in the system xml, which I already did and which gave nothing. I also found out that qemu uses some "qom-get" script to actually measure stats, but I cannot use it from

```
virsh # qemu-monitor-command 1 --hmp "qom-get"
```

(outputs that command is unknown) and I cannot see it in my PATH. Also `pacman -Fo qom-get` and `pkgfile qom-get` give nothing.
My host system is Arch Linux. The contents of the win7.xml are

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>win7</name>
  <uuid>438145c1-a2df-4c86-96d6-2bf7b379d70b</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static' current='2'>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-2.9'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv>
      <relaxed state='on'/>
      <vapic state='on'/>
      <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
    </hyperv>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='partial'>
    <model fallback='allow'>Broadwell-noTSX</model>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
    <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/sbin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/win7.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <target dev='hdb' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/usr/share/virtio/virtio-win.iso'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:9d:4e:85'/>
      <source network='default'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='spice' autoport='yes'>
      <listen type='address'/>
      <image compression='off'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='3'/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <stats period='10'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

I am definitely missing something, but I cannot see what. Could anyone, please, give me any useful links or guides? I would really appreciate it.

This is duplicate of [question on Arch Linux newbie forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=228347). If anyone will give the appropriate answer, I will share it with the other site.

================================================

UPD. balloon is working: I can do such things as

```
virsh # qemu-monitor-command win7 --hmp "info balloon"
balloon: actual=4096
virsh # qemu-monitor-command win7 --hmp "balloon 2048"
virsh # qemu-monitor-command win7 --hmp "info balloon"
balloon: actual=2048
```

But the qom-get won't do:

```
virsh # qemu-monitor-command windows7 '{ "execute": "qom-get",  "arguments": { "path": "/machine/peripheral/balloon0",  "property": "guest-stats" } }'
{"return":{"stats":{"stat-swap-out":-1,"stat-available-memory":-1,"stat-free-memory":-1,"stat-minor-faults":-1,"stat-major-faults":-1,"stat-total-memory":-1,"stat-swap-in":-1},"last-update":1500639136},"id":"libvirt-396"}
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the *Balloon* service wasn't installed properly. If you face same problem, possible solution will be to open command line, go to the CD-ROM with VirtIO drivers, go to Balloon directory and deeper, depending on your system and architecture. When you are in *amd64* (*x86*) directory, type

```
blnsrv.exe -i
```

and the service should install itself. After that the problem will be gone (at least, this worked for me).